# using docusign v1 api cannot sgn the document due to failed security

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign REST API version 1 to test sending/signing documents. However, in the course of my testing I forgot the security question answers and now cannot sign the document. Using demo.docusign.com for testing.

Thanks, Jason

Comment: Not related to your issue, but -- you I'd suggest you use REST API v2 (instead of v1), as v2 contains many more features than v1.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve issues like this you need to contact your DocuSign Account Manager who can reset your account, as was done in this case.

If you do not have an Account Manager assigned yet then reach out to `support@docusign.com` and provide your `DocuSign Account ID`.